# System Overload. The audio engine was not able to process all required data in time.

Tags: equalization, macosx

I need to equalize my system, want to use software-based solution, preferably free. 
On windows computer I used Equalizer APO and was very happy with it.
On MacOS i've found this excellent guide https://superuser.com/a/321791/144657 . 
Soundflower+AU Lab  worked as inteded, sounded good.

But I faced big problem with it: after a minute or two the sound starts buzzing, like it's clipped, the intensity of it quickly rises, and then in AU Lab the message appears "System Overload. The audio engine was not able to process all required data in time.", and the sound gets back to normal again, and this cycle begins again.

My computer is base model 2013 Macbook Air, should have enough power, no process us using more than 20% of CPU while playing.
Tried Jack Audio with the same result even before inserting AU Lab in the chain.

Comment: What OS? Soundflower hasn't been very good since about Mountain Lion/Mavericks. Can break badly on Yosemite. I had to stop using it. If you can increase buffer size anywhere in that chain, it may help.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really used Soundflower but it looks like your having a loop in your audio system.
Try finding if your audio routing has any leaks also it can come from an external 
device plugged inside your computer.
Do multiple tests:

- unplug as much external devices as you can
- make sure all mic inputs are disabled in your System Preference->Audio
- you can also try catch up suspicious CPU usage on your Activity Monitor.